# Google Sign In with Firebase fails

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement an Google Auth method using Firebase, but the sign in fails. The Logcat doesn't show me any red text when it fails. I got my SHA 1 set up but it still doesn't work. I use Kotlin.

LoginActivity.kt

```
package com.example.madistrezsieu

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
import android.widget.Toast.makeText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.madistrezsieu.MainActivity
import com.example.madistrezsieu.R
import com.example.madistrezsieu.view.User
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*


class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var authStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener? = null
    private var googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
    private var rootRef: FirebaseFirestore? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        google_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener { signIn() }

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
            val firebaseUser = auth.currentUser
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }

        val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(applicationContext)
            .enableAutoManage(this) { makeText(this, "You got a GoogleApiClient Error!", LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build()
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val googleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
                    firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleSignInAccount)
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                makeText(this, "Google sign in failed!", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(googleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.idToken, null)
        firebaseAuth!!.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
            val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth!!.currentUser
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                createUserIfNotExists(firebaseUser)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createUserIfNotExists(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser) {
        val uid = firebaseUser.uid
        val userName = firebaseUser.displayName
        val user = User(uid, userName!!)

        val uidRef = rootRef!!.collection("users").document(uid)
        uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val document = task.result
                if (!document!!.exists()) {
                    uidRef.set(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        firebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener!!)
    }

    public override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (firebaseAuth != null) {
            firebaseAuth!!.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener!!)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        //private val TAG = "LoginActivity"
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 123
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem could be, should I make another Android Studio project and copy paste the code, and then add another app in the Firebase Project?

LOGCAT

```
06-12 15:08:23.264 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{c73e49c u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity}
06-12 15:08:23.334 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{c73e49c u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity}
06-12 15:08:23.374 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{15692e6 u0 com.example.madistrezsieu/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}
06-12 15:08:23.544 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{1ccc6a0 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.signin.activity.SignInActivity}
06-12 15:08:25.174 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{de116d2 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity}
06-12 15:08:26.354 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{1187be7 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.OriginalAccountChipAccountPickerActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.044 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{6a14a0b u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountChipAccountPickerActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.074 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{1ccc6a0 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.signin.activity.SignInActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.744 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{de116d2 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.764 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{c73e49c u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.824 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{15692e6 u0 com.example.madistrezsieu/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.834 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{d14245b u0 com.example.madistrezsieu/com.example.madistrezsieu.LoginActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.834 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{d14245b u0 com.example.madistrezsieu/com.example.madistrezsieu.LoginActivity}
06-12 15:08:28.894 2897-2897/com.example.madistrezsieu D/WHATTHEFUCK: EROARE
06-12 15:08:33.884 1383-2275/? D/AlarmManager: sending alarm PendingIntent{bcc15b6: PendingIntentRecord{49e31a2 com.whatsapp broadcastIntent}}, i=com.whatsapp.MessageHandler.CLIENT_PINGER_ACTION, t=2, cnt=1, w=2614648, Int=240000
06-12 15:08:46.924 1383-3180/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x3200000 which=0x1 pkg=com.android.systemui
06-12 15:08:46.954 1383-1428/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x400000 which=0x1 pkg=Window{72431d1 u0 StatusBar}
06-12 15:08:48.854 2930-3536/? I/ContextualWidget: handleMessage, what=1028 mode=GettingOut maxcount=8
```

Comment: Have you enable google sign In from Firebase console?

Comment: Yes, I did enable.

Comment: Can you show what exactly is the error . ?What exactly is the error code ?

Comment: Put your `Log` here.

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the Log in the post

Comment: I cannot see in that log message any exception thrown. Try to log the messages from any errors from the tasks you intend to get.

Comment: I fixed it, I just didn't set the support email

Answer (score 2):

[image: Last but not the least , your google sign in should be enabled]Just check while setting up the project in firebase , have you added the support email in public setting ? [image: Enter the support email and check if you have the latest google-services.json file inside your app level of project] . As i have faced the same issue few days back , and the only thing which was missing is Support email id in my firebase console .

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks a lot !